# Problem creating a Windows 10 bootable USB on Windows, to work on a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, startup, bootable-disk

I have a MacBook Pro 2013, now with a clean SSD (no OS).

I have a Windows 10 PC from which I am trying to create a bootable USB from a Windows 10 ISO file.

I tried a lot of combinations and softwares, but when I plug the USB on MacBook Pro, click options and then select UEFI, the screen just stays black, it is not recognizing the installation program.

Can anyone share a method to create this USB on Windows in a manner that the MacBook Pro will recognize it?

Comment: I'm confused. From what you've written it sounds like you're trying to install Windows 10 from an ISO loaded on a USB key onto the clean SSD in the MBP. Please confirm with some clarification if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to install Windows 10 on the MacBookPro 2013. Your question does not provide enough information that can be used to generate an exact answer. I would need to know which version of firmware is currently installed on your Mac. This firmware is tied to the latest version of macOS (OS X) that was installed on your Mac. You may need later firmware to boot the Windows 10 installer from an ExFAT formatted volume. Also, I would need to know the Windows 10 ISO version and how the ISO was obtained. The contains of early Windows 10 ISOs would fit on FAT32 formatted volumes. The latest Windows 10 ISOs can contain an `install.wim` file that exceeds 4 GB file limit of FAT32 formatted volumes. However, the latest Windows 10 ISOs download on a PC using the Media Creation Tool may instead contain a `install.esd` file that would fit on a FAT32 formatted volume. However, Apple recommends using the Windows 10 ISO directly downloaded from the internet.

Finally, to install Windows 10, you need the correct Windows Support Software for your model Mac. The usual method of acquiring the Windows Support Software is by directing the Boot Camp Assistant to download. This would require first installing the latest macOS compatible with your Mac. After downloading to an external drive, you can erase the internal SSD. Using the Boot Camp Assistant installed on a different Mac will probably result in the wrong Windows Support Software being downloaded. You can also download the Windows Support Software using a PC, but this is a far more complicated process. Therefore, I would recommend using the PC to download the Windows Support Software only as a last resort.